# cmake incorrectly escapes bison target option

Tags: cmake

Take this minimized [example](https://github.com/tilir/cpp-graduate/blob/master/07-parsers/advgrammar/CMakeLists.txt)

Critical place:

```
bison_target(parser
  numgrammar.y
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/parser.cc
  COMPILE_FLAGS "--defines=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/numgrammar.tab.hh")
```

Then please create some folder with space inside name like:

```
> mkdir "test folder" && cd "test folder"
> cmake ${ADVGRAMMAR}
> make VERBOSE=1
```

You will see something like:

```
> /usr/bin/bison --defines=/mnt/c/research/test folder/advgrammar/build/numgrammar.tab.hh -d -o ....
```

You see the problem: space in "test folder" not escaped.

Ok, now lets try to escape:

```
bison_target(parser
  numgrammar.y
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/parser.cc
  COMPILE_FLAGS "--defines=\"${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/numgrammar.tab.hh\"")
```

You will see:

```
/usr/bin/bison --defines=\"/mnt/c/research/test folder/advgrammar/build/numgrammar.tab.hh\" -d -o ....
```

Now cmake added wrong escape mark for quotes.

Of course no problem if cmake in some neutral-named folder without spaces, but I want any folder.

I tried to google really hard. I tried string with CONFIGURE, I tried generator expressions, I tried this and that and everything and looks like I can't get behavior I want.

I want simply this:

```
/usr/bin/bison --defines="/mnt/c/research/test folder/advgrammar/build/numgrammar.tab.hh" -d -o ....
```

Of course I can do it with my own custom target. But I want this with bison_target.

Really need cmake experts help. Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can have a solution w/o modifying the module as it seems like a bug to me, so feel free to file a bug report. As a workaround, try the following: `string(REPLACE " " [[\\040]] compile_flags "${compile_flags}")` where `compile_flags` is `set(compile_flags "--defines=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/numgrammar.tab.hh")`. Then pass the escaped version to the macro. You might need to find a correct number of slashes before `040` but from skimming over the findBison module, I think, it should be enough.

Comment: Also, maybe single quotes might help: `COMPILE_FLAGS "--defines='${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/numgrammar.tab.hh'"`

Comment: Thanks, @ixSci for suggestion, created issue https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/23301

Comment: Single quotes don't help. I can see: /usr/bin/bison "--defines='/mnt/c/research/test" "folder/advgrammar/build/numgrammar.tab.hh'" ....

Comment: @ixSci - you can ~always hack around a module bug with `variable_watch`  see my answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `bison_target` macro calls<sup>1</sup> [`separate_arguments`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/separate_arguments.html) on the value of the `COMPILE_FLAGS`  without using the new form that respects native shell rules (it just blindly replaces spaces with semicolons).

Unfortunately, the macro doesn't give you a chance to inject flags in a more modern way, either, so the best I could come up with was to use the `variable_watch` command  to hack at the internals of `bison_target`, at least until this bug is fixed.

Here's a full example:

```makefile
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(test)

find_package(FLEX REQUIRED)
find_package(BISON REQUIRED)

# Hack around FindBISON's incorrect use of separate_arguments
if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 3.24)
  function(patch_flags variable access value ip stack)
    set(invalid "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")
    separate_arguments(invalid)
    string(REPLACE "${invalid}" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}" "${variable}" "${value}")
    set("${variable}" "${${variable}}" PARENT_SCOPE)
  endfunction()
  variable_watch(BISON_TARGET_cmdopt patch_flags)
endif ()

flex_target(scanner
  numgrammar.l
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lexer.cc"
)

bison_target(
  parser
  numgrammar.y
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/parser.cc"
  COMPILE_FLAGS "--defines=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/numgrammar.tab.hh"
)

add_flex_bison_dependency(scanner parser)

add_executable(
  numgrammar
  driver.cc
  ${BISON_parser_OUTPUTS}
  ${FLEX_scanner_OUTPUTS}
)
```

And here's a shell interaction:

```
$ cmake -G Ninja -S . -B "build with space"
$ cmake --build "build with space" -- -nv  # n = dry-run, v = verbose
[1/6] cd "/home/alex/test/build with space" && /usr/bin/bison "--defines=/home/alex/test/build with space/numgrammar.tab.hh" -d -o "/home/alex/test/build with space/parser.cc" /home/alex/test/numgrammar.y
[2/6] cd "/home/alex/test/build with space" && /usr/bin/flex "-o/home/alex/test/build with space/lexer.cc" /home/alex/test/numgrammar.l
[3/6] /usr/bin/c++    -MD -MT CMakeFiles/numgrammar.dir/driver.cc.o -MF CMakeFiles/numgrammar.dir/driver.cc.o.d -o CMakeFiles/numgrammar.dir/driver.cc.o -c /home/alex/test/driver.cc
[4/6] /usr/bin/c++    -MD -MT CMakeFiles/numgrammar.dir/parser.cc.o -MF CMakeFiles/numgrammar.dir/parser.cc.o.d -o CMakeFiles/numgrammar.dir/parser.cc.o -c '/home/alex/test/build with space/parser.cc'
[5/6] /usr/bin/c++    -MD -MT CMakeFiles/numgrammar.dir/lexer.cc.o -MF CMakeFiles/numgrammar.dir/lexer.cc.o.d -o CMakeFiles/numgrammar.dir/lexer.cc.o -c '/home/alex/test/build with space/lexer.cc'
[6/6] : && /usr/bin/c++   CMakeFiles/numgrammar.dir/driver.cc.o CMakeFiles/numgrammar.dir/parser.cc.o CMakeFiles/numgrammar.dir/lexer.cc.o -o numgrammar   && :
```

As you can see the bison rule correctly quotes the spaces.

```
... /usr/bin/bison "--defines=/home/alex/test/build with space/numgrammar.tab.hh" ...
```

<sup>1. See https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/6b6bdcbb64e1aa2ddac4f09a0807553f5684165a/Modules/FindBISON.cmake#L131 and https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/6b6bdcbb64e1aa2ddac4f09a0807553f5684165a/Modules/FindBISON.cmake#L249</sup>

Comment: Nice hack! I used to modify & keep the "bad" module in the repo before but that looks like an interesting method to use.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case: there is an option `DEFINES_FILE` in the `bison_target` macro. As for me it looks like more portable. You can use it instead of `COMPILE_FLAGS`.

```
bison_target(parser
             numgrammar.y
             ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/parser.cc
             ## COMPILE_FLAGS "--defines=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/numgrammar.tab.hh")
             DEFINES_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/numgrammar.tab.hh
  )
```

It works fine at least on Catalina.

```
$ cmake -G Ninja -S . -B "build with spaces"
$ cmake --build "build with spaces" -- -nv
[1/6] cd /Users/tonnyred/td && /usr/local/opt/bison/bin/bison "--defines=/Users/tonnyred/td/build with spaces/numgrammar.tab.hh" -o "/Users/tonnyred/td/build with spaces/parser.cc" numgrammar.y
[2/6] cd /Users/tonnyred/td && /usr/local/opt/flex/bin/flex "-o/Users/tonnyred/td/build with spaces/lexer.cc" numgrammar.l
...
```